# Macro fails when run but works when stepping through

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I am working with a 2 axis chart showing volume with columns and YoY change with no visual representation only data labels. I have written a macro to uniformly move the YoY data labels above each column. The macro works perfectly when stepping through but fails when run.

```
Sub Move_Data_Point_1_chart()
    Set chrt_obj_sig = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Volume & YoY")
    Set chrt_sig = chrt_obj_sig.Chart
    pnt_cnt = chrt_sig.SeriesCollection(1).Points.Count
    
    chrt_sig.FullSeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.Position = xlLabelPositionInsideEnd
            
    For i = 1 To pnt_cnt
        chrt_sig_pt = chrt_sig.SeriesCollection(1).Points(i).DataLabel.Top
        chrt_sig.SeriesCollection(2).Points(i).DataLabel.Top = chrt_sig_pt - 18
    Next i
    
    chrt_sig.FullSeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.Position = xlLabelPositionCenter
End Sub
```

Here is my expected output.
[Correct Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHb2f.png)

Here is the failed output.
[Incorrect Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fPBu.png)

Any suggestions for fixing this?

I have searched and found many similar occurrences but nothing I could apply to my specific situation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: **fails when run**: unfortunately this doesn't tell us anything about your issue. Does it throw an error? if so, what is it? If not, what does it do that it's not suppose to? Also, try qualifying your sheet rather than `ActiveSheet`. This is fraught with danger

Comment: Sorry, should have explained "fail" better. When running the macro it does not correctly move the secondary data labels. There are 2 pictures in my original post to show what my expected output should be and what I get when I run the macro. Not sure why it would work stepping through but not when running it.

Comment: Any reason not to use `xlLabelPositionOutsideEnd`?

Comment: I am trying show volume with each column, that data label is to be centered in each column. Additionally showing YoY change with an overlapping column with not color. The intent is to show the YoY change above the volume column. The YoY value rarely lines up with the volume making it necessary to adjust its position.